# Merging two C++ libraries with the same name function

Tags: c++, lib

I have two libraries with the names uart.h and spi.h

Both of them have functions where the names are the same but the implementation are different.

For example in uart.h, we have `void SetValue()`Function with uart implementation and in spi.h we have the same function name but with spi implementation.

I want to merge these two libraries to one library with preprocessor directives (`#ifdef` `#define` ...) employer wants me to use this way for merging.

We want to ask user in main.c file to determine the protocol (uart or spi) and depending on the user definition in main.c file we write the library.

Comment: Don't tag a question with both C and C++ tags unless you're particularly fond of downvotes or your question is about the interworking of the two languages.  Your question satisfies neither criterion.

Comment: You may want to utilize templates and their specializations for that. Cleaner, safer. Other than that: what exactly is the problem? What stops you from using those preprocessor directives?

Comment: You don't actually ask a question. If your goal is to use `#ifdef` then what's the problem with doing that?

Comment: Best way is to wrap one of libraries with own library which will expose required API from a namespace of your choosing. Do not even think about macros here.

Comment: Please specify library names, provide links to them and make sure that symbol name you are providing is correct one. (When I've tried google those libraries none of them have `SetValue`).

Comment: Normally, `uart.h` would be called a header — a header that describes the facilities provided by some library.  There are 'header only' libraries.   But it grates (to me) to hear headers called libraries.

Comment: Which is the question?

Comment: You probably have to provide more detail. I am not sure how much we can help with code we know so little about.

Answer (score 0):

If you have C++ headers that define functions with general names they should better be using namespaces. Then you would have `UART::SetValue()` and no problem.

The next thing is: Why isn't UART a class with methods? The UART is an object, it has a location in memory (in most archs) and you can have multiple UARTs in a system. Does UART's `SetValue()` take an extra argument which uart you mean?

Once you have the two functions separated you can merge them and use #ifdef constructs to pick one of the two as default.